# how to separate ajax response in multiple variables and how to call them?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i am using ajax to fetch data from database and showing it in the text box. the examples i saw on the web works so far if you want to show the ajax response in one text box only. how do we separate it if we want to get multiple variables of php from ajaxresponse and store it on the request page in multiple text boxes. below is the example:

PAGE 1(AJAX REQUEST)

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput" id="label">Student ID :</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="std_id" type="text" placeholder="Student ID" name="std_id"  onKeyUp="get_student();" required>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput" id="label">Student Name:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="std_name" type="text" placeholder="Student Name" name="std_name" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput" id="label">Semester :</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="semester" type="text" placeholder="Semester" name="semester" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput" id="label">Room #:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="r_num" type="text" placeholder="Room Number" name="r_num" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT & AJAX REQUEST CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function get_student()
    {
        var std_id=document.getElementById("std_id").value;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)  
            {
                document.getElementById("std_name").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","AjaxResponse.php?std_id="+std_id+",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

PAGE 2(AJAX RESPONSE):

```
<?php

    $std_id=$_GET['std_id'];
    $select_std_dtls=mysql_query("SELECT tbl_student_module.std_name,tbl_room_allotment_module.r_num,MAX(tbl_fee_module.semester) AS SEM FROM tbl_room_allotment_module INNER JOIN tbl_student_module ON tbl_room_allotment_module.std_id=tbl_student_module.std_id INNER JOIN tbl_fee_module ON tbl_student_module.std_id=tbl_student_module.std_id WHERE tbl_room_allotment_module.std_id=".$std_id." AND tbl_fee_module.std_id=".$std_id." AND tbl_room_allotment_module.a_status='active'")or die(mysql_error($select_std_dtls));

    if($row=mysql_fetch_array($select_std_dtls))
    {
        $db_std_name=$row['std_name'];
        $db_r_num=$row['r_num'];
        $db_semester=$row['SEM']+1;
    }

    echo $db_std_name,$db_r_num,$db_semester;

?>
```

Here you can see the ajax response will be shown in Student Name text field but i want to separate all the ajax response and show them in separate fields. please help. thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you really need to support IE 5 and 6? anyway: `echo json_encode($row);`

Comment: not really actually that is an example i saw on site and i don't have much knowledge about json so it means i have to learn json first or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two changes I would make to do as you've asked.

The first is to delimit the response coming back from the PHP page. This means that you separate the different parts of the data with an arbitrary character, such as a comma, a tilde, or a pipe, which is one of my favorite. You could do that along these lines:

```
echo "$db_std_name|$db_r_num|$db_semester"
```

Then, in your AJAX handler, you can separate the data as place it as you please.
Instead of:

```
document.getElementById("std_name").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

You would first split the data by the delimiter into its parts, then assign it appropriately:

```
var parts = xmlhttp.responseText.split('|')
document.getElementById("std_name").value = parts[0]
document.getElementById("r_num").value = parts[1]
document.getElementById("semester").value = parts[2]
```

Or something along those lines. I would probably assign the data to labels if it is meant to be read, instead of edited.

Comment: I would add that the answer from Andreas is better for complex data if you are willing to change your method to using JSON.

Comment: Miles i also think json would be the best way as everyone is focusing on the same thing but i think my data is not so complex so i will try your method first. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A quick answer is to encode your result array on your php page as json

```
`echo encode_json($row);`
```

And then you will have access to your results as a json object with key value pairs

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution would be a JSON based response. If you wanna do this you have to change your PHP like the following:

```php
<?php
$std_id=$_GET['std_id'];
$sql = <<<HERE_ENDS_SQL
SELECT tbl_student_module.std_name,tbl_room_allotment_module.r_num,MAX(tbl_fee_module.semester) AS SEM
  FROM tbl_room_allotment_module
 INNER JOIN tbl_student_module ON tbl_room_allotment_module.std_id=tbl_student_module.std_id
 INNER JOIN tbl_fee_module ON tbl_student_module.std_id=tbl_student_module.std_id
 WHERE tbl_room_allotment_module.std_id=$std_id
   AND tbl_fee_module.std_id=$std_id
   AND tbl_room_allotment_module.a_status='active'
HERE_ENDS_SQL;

$select_std_dtls = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($select_std_dtls));

$result = '{}';
if($row=mysql_fetch_array($select_std_dtls))
{
    $result = json_encode([
        'std_name' => $row['std_name'],
        'r_num' => $row['r_num'],
        'semester' => $row['SEM'] + 1,
    ]);
}

echo $result;
```

After that you have to change the callback-function of your ajax like the following:

```
function () {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        document.getElementById("std_name").value=jsonObj.std_name;
        document.getElementById("r_num").value=jsonObj.r_num;
        document.getElementById("semester").value=jsonObj.semester;
    }
};
```

That should work for you. But you have still some SQL-Injections in it and it is still not best practised, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I recommmend to send the respond to the ajax url (AjaxResponse.php?std_id=x) with a json format. See http://www.json.org

This allows you to separate variables, for example by using an array:

```
[
 { "name":"John" , "semester":"2" }, 
 { "name":"Anna" , "semester":"3" }
]
```

Then, in the browser, you can parse this json format into a javascript array:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your result in array in php file and return to HTML using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

for example:

```
      echo json_encode($result_array);
```

And use bellow function in javascript:

- [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)
- [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)

  ```
  student_record = JSON.parse(msg);
  ```